# Complex function with values on the unit circle copied everywhere

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, analytic-functions

If $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}\to \mathbb{C}$ is a function such that $f(z)=f(\frac z{|z|})$ and its restriction to unit circle is continous,then

$(1)\lim _{z\to 0} f(z)$ exist.

$(2)f$ is analytic but not necessarily a constant function

$(3)f$ is continous but not necessarily analytic.

$(4)f$ is a constant function.

The title can be justified in the following way:-

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$, Then $f(re^{i\theta})=f(e^{i\theta})$

Hence, I can imagine rays of equal values radiating out from zero in every direction .

Now ,if $z=re^{i\theta}$, then as $r\to 0$, then $z\to 0$

$\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=
\lim_{r\to 0}f(e^{i\theta})=f(e^{i\theta})$, which depends on $\theta$ and hence the limit does not exist.

I am quite confident that there exist no such non-constant analytic function but it is getting difficult for me to write an analytical proof. (I tried to arrive at a contradiction assuming $f$ is a analytic on  a bounded domain and using maximum modulus theorem but I failed.)

Since the restriction of $f$ to the unit circle is continous, that means for any fixed $\theta_0$, $\lim_{\theta\to \theta_0}f(e^{i\theta})=f(e^{i\theta_0})$

Now let $z_0=r_0e^{i\theta_0}, z=re^{i\theta}$ and $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given, then $|f(z_0)-f(z)| =|f(e^{i\theta_0})-f(e^{i\theta})|\lt \epsilon $, 
if $| \theta-\theta_0|\lt \delta$, where the existence of $\delta$ for $\epsilon$ is garaunteed by continuity of $f$ on the unit circle.

So $f$ is continous.

$f$ may not be constant as suggested by above proof.

Please go through my work and help me complete it.

Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: For $f$ to be continuous in $0$ we need, as you noted, $f(e^{i\vartheta})$ to be constant. As the values on the unit circle are copied everywhere, this implies that $f$ is constant. Thus $f$ is continuous iff it is constant iff it is analytic.

Comment: @Caffeine..Thanks for the suggestion, but isn't your argument valid only when $0$ is considered a point of the domain , while it is not so  as given in the question. Sorry if I am wrong , but I can't answer this to myself.

Comment: if the domain is not assumed to be $\mathbb{C}$, $\frac{z}{|z|}$ offers an answer to $(3)-(4)$. For $(2)$ note that in $0$ the function has a removable singularity

Comment: Your question is rather confusing. As it is, one could think that you want to prove (1) - (4). " ..., then ..." The correct question is which of (1) - (4) are true.

Answer (score 1):

- Let $f(z)=\frac{z}{|z|}$, it is continuous in $\Bbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$.
  Therefore,
  $f(f(z))=f(\frac{z}{|z|})=f(z).$
  composition of two continuous function is continuous. Thus $f$ is continuous.
  $f$ is not analytic. one can check it by **Cauchy-Riemann** equation.
- clearly, $f(z)=\frac{z}{|z|}$ is not constant.
- Limit does not exist as $z\to 0$, one can check easily.
  $f(x+iy)=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x+iy}{x ^2+y^2}$.

Comment: With this compact form of the Cauchy-Riemann equation(s), $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} =0$, by inspection your function is not analytic.  But $\textit{a priori}$, why do you assume $f$ takes that form?

Comment: $f(z)= \frac{z}{{\left| z \right|}}$ is a continuous map from $\mathbb{C}\setminus 
\left\{ 0 \right\}$ to the unit circle and by assumption $f$ is continuous on the unit circle.

Comment: Also, $f(z)=5$ is a continuous map from $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}$ to the unit circle and continuous on the unit circle.

Comment: @mjw As op did above...**if $z=re^{i\theta}$, then as $r\to 0$, then $z\to 0$ $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)= \lim_{r\to 0}f(e^{i\theta})=f(e^{i\theta})$, which depends on $\theta$ and hence the limit does not exist**. That's why we choose a particular function.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you have set out to show.  Since there are functions that satisfy the hypotheses, but do not satisfy (1), (2), (4), these are not (always) true.  Got it.  It remains to show (3) always holds, right?

Comment: Yeah...Right:)${}{}$

Comment: Looks like you are very close!  Why not let $g(z) = \frac{z}{|z|}$, etc.

Comment: @mjw You can go with that... Let $g(z)=\frac{z}{|z|}$, it is continuous from $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ to $\Bbb{C}$, and $f(g(z))=f(\frac{z}{|z|})=f(z)$...and so on...

Comment: Right.  Agreed.${}{}{}$